# scala - get class from a string

Tags: scala

From Scala, I'm using a Java library that expects a class argument.  Example:

```
def service: OAuthService  = new ServiceBuilder()
                                    .provider(classOf[RunApi])
```

RunApi is Java class.

I'd like to be able pass a variety of classes to provider though.  I have a list of them in String format.

Example, if I know the RunApi in String format; e.g. "com.me.RunApi", how can construct the equivalent to above code?

Answer (score 18):

Use `forName` method:

```
scala> Class.forName("scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer")
res0: java.lang.Class[_] = class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
```

Comment: Thanks, thought it was going to work, but: [error]   (org.scribe.builder.api.Api)org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder <and>
[error]   (java.lang.Class[_ <: org.scribe.builder.api.Api])org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder
[error]  cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class[?0(in method service)])
[error]                                     .provider(Class.forName("com.me.RunApi"))
[error]                                      ^
[error] one error found

Comment: Just cast it to the required type: `Class.forName("com.me.RunApi").asInstanceOf[Class[_ <: org.scribe.builder.api.Api]]`.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that as well as Class.forName("com.me.RunApi").asInstanceOf(Api), but: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to org.scribe.builder.api.Api.  RunApi extends an abstract parent class which implements Api interface.

Answer (score 1):

val yourInstance: ClassOrTrait = Class.forName("Package.ClassName").newInstance().asInstanceOf[ClassOrTrait]