# Define Generic Types with String

Tags: scala

How do you define a generic with a string? For example, if I wanted to write

```
 def createMap(foo: String, bar: String) = {
   Map[foo, bar]()
 }

 val myMap = createMap("String", "Int")
```

How could I transform foo and bar to the correct types? I'm not seeing much in the documentation about this.

Comment: The whole point of generics is to be type-safe at compile time.  You're trying to defeat that.

Comment: And what would you expect the return type of `createMap` to be, then?

Comment: You could use macros to do that (I'll give you an example if you need it), but know that the strings then **must** be literals in order for it to work. Please describe your use case, we might give you another solution.

Comment: Use case: Map[Foo,Bar](f->Bar(f)), where Foo and Bar are classes to be loaded (by context loader or implicit param), hence, createMap("Foo", "Bar")("foo"). You can create a mirror for the class loader; can you import the symbols into currentMirror to operate on them usefully?  So, yes, reflection is trying to defeat a facile distinction between compile-time and run-time type safety.  Just ask ClassTag.

Answer (score 2):

1. Look:

   ```
   def createMap[foo, bar] = {
     Map[foo, bar]()
   }

   val myMap = createMap[`String`, `Int`]
   ```

   Doesn't it look similar to the required code?
2. If you really wish to create a map at runtime with types unknown at compile time, then you can simply use `Map[Any, Any]()` + type casts. I don't think it is possible to achieve type safety with string type identifiers.
   (To obtain a class for runtime check see [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9268925/2646454))
3. It seems that [macros](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) can be used. However I'm not an expert to provide the implementation.

Comment: +1 for just replacing stuff in the example. Especially the back-ticks.