# How do I specify type parameters via a configuration file?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I am building a market simulator using Scala/Akka/Play. I have an Akka actor with two children.  The children need to have specific types which I would like to specify as parameters.

Suppose that I have the following class definition...

```
case class SecuritiesMarket[A <: AuctionMechanismLike, C <: ClearingMechanismLike](instrument: Security) extends Actor
  with ActorLogging {

  val auctionMechanism: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[A], "auction-mechanism")

  val clearingMechanism: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[C], "clearing-mechanism")

  def receive: Receive = {
    case order: OrderLike => auctionMechanism forward order
    case fill: FillLike => clearingMechanism forward fill
  }

}
```

Instances of this class can be created as follows...

```
val stockMarket = SecuritiesMarket[DoubleAuctionMechanism, CCPClearingMechanism](Security("GOOG"))
val derivativesMarket = SecuritiesMarket[BatchAuctionMechanism, BilateralClearingMechanism](Security("SomeDerivative"))
```

There are many possible combinations of auction mechanism types and clearing mechanism types that I might use when creating `SecuritiesMarket` instance for a particular model/simulation.

Can I specify the type parameters that I wish to use in a given simulation in the `application.conf` file?

Comment: There is always the possibility to match a string read from the conf file. Though there are probably better ways.

Answer (score 2):

I see two questions here.

#### Can I get a `Class` instance from a String?

[Yes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268873/scala-get-class-from-a-string)

```
val cls: Class[DoubleAuctionMechanism] = Class.forName("your.app.DoubleAuctionMechanism").asInstanceOf[Class[DoubleAuctionMechanism]]
```

You would still need the cast, as `forName` returns `Class[_]`.

#### Can I instantiate a type with type parameters are not known compile time?

Well sort of, but not really.

```
object SecuritiesMarket {
    def apply[A, C](clsAuc: Class[A], clsClr: Class[C])(security: Security): SecuritiesMarket[A, C] = {
        SecuritiesMarket[A, C](security)
    }
}
```

---

I think auction mechanisms and clearing mechanisms are dependencies for `SecurityMarket`. I'm guessing you instantiate them in its constructor somehow (how?). If that's the case why not just pass them in as a constructor parameter?

**Edit:**

> I don't see how I could create the child actors inside SecurityMarket

Answering this in the comments; `Props[T]` can also be written as `Props[T](classOfT)`, which can be simplified as `Props(classOfT)`. Those three are the same. So the following code:

```
val auctionMechanism: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[A], "auction-mechanism")
```

Can be replaced with:

```
val classOfA = Class.forName("path.to.A")
val auctionMechanism: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props(classOfA), "auction-mechanism")
```

Comment: Indeed auction mechanisms and clearing mechanisms are dependencies for `SecurityMarket`.  Their `ActorRefs` are instantiated in the code above via the `context.actorOf` calls. If I created instances of `AuctionMechanismLike` and `ClearingMechanismLike` and then passed these as constructor params I don't see how I could create the child actors inside `SecurityMarket`.

Comment: For clarification, if the type parameter values were specified in the `application.conf` file then aren't these values known at compile time? Code is compiled based on information contained in various `*.conf` files? Or not?

Comment: The type system works its magic compile time. If your code compiles, you have the type guarantees (well, sort of). I'm adding something else in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

First, application.conf is a runtime artifact and its contents are as far as I know not normally parsed at compile time. When the file is parsed at runtime, the parser creates an instance of the class Config which then controls the Akka setup.

The Typesafe Config library project readme is quite nice and the linked documentation has all of the details:

https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/README.md.

Second, since template parameters are not available at runtime because of type erasure, you can't normally use application.conf to control templating. You could create a custom build step to parse application.conf and modify your code before compilation, but this is maybe not what you want. (And if you do want a custom build step, perhaps a different .conf would be appropriate.)

Instead you might try simply eliminating the type parameters for the securities market class. Then create a single, simple implementation of the auction and clearing *actors*. Implement these actors by reading the names of the respective *mechanisms* from application.conf, instantiating the configured mechanism reflectively, and delegating to the instantiated mechanism. The mechanism classes could be independent of Akka, which is perhaps nice if that's where you keep most of your logic?

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Given that `application.conf` is a runtime object perhaps I should be wiring the dependencies at compile time?  Is it possible to do this.

Comment: Yes of course - that would let you avoid reflection. The simplest way is to specialize the securities market class for the different combinations of auction and clearing mechanisms that you need. Yes, you might get a lot of specialization classes, but each one would only be a line of code or so.

You might alternatively use an injection library, like Spring or Guice. Your application.conf could refer to a bean identifier. The bean definition would refer auction and clearing mechanism beans. Maybe that would fit the bill?

Comment: OK.  So using, say, Spring I can specify the compile time wiring of dependencies that I want to use in order to create the various markets, then in the `application.conf` I effectively specify the specific combination that I want to use for a particular simulation.  This would allow me to avoid writing all the various combinations of markets out at the expense of using Spring (or Guice).  Have I got the tradeoff correct?